# Unique Combination with Frequency Restriction

Tags: algorithm, math, greedy, approximation, np

I am a python developer and I am working on a python script with make unique combination from a list of numbers. I found out how to archive this with python module; itertools.

```
from itertools import combinations
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
combs = list(combinations(alist, 6))
```

Above code gets a list of all unique combinations in which length of each element is 6.
e.x: (1,2,3,4,5,6), (1,2,3,4,5,7)...

What I like to do is to apply frequency restriction on each element. So if I set 1's limit as 50%, up to 50% of elements in unique combinations contain element 1. And I like to get as big as possible combination set.

I think this is a kind of NP problem so we should use Greedy or other Approximation Algorithm but I can't figure out the way. Please help me with your own idea about this problem.

Comment: `50% of elements in unique combinations contain element 1`- this phrase is not clear. Do you want element repeats? Please provide  small example.

Comment: @MBo: Let's assume we have unique combinations set (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (2, 3, 4). 
On this set, the % of 1 is 67.33%. So if I set the % of 1 as 50% then my result is the set (1,2,3 ), (2,3,4)

Comment: OK, now I do understand.